# Merging all files with union and triggering mergetool

Tags: git

I have the following scenario: I made a couple of commits on one branch, then I used a tool which generates code from a UML model on a new branch. Unfortunately this tool is rather dumb and does not properly support round-trip generation. Hence, all of my code was removed and only the generated skeleton was kept.

I would like to merge these two branches by keeping all lines from both versions of the files (and ideally triggering the mergetool on each file).

What I did so far:

I created a shell script in the root of the working tree:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "union merge"
git merge-file --union "${1}" "${2}" "${3}"
exit 1 # trigger merge conflict
```

Created a .gitattributes file:

```
**.cpp merge=mytool
**.h merge=mytool
```

And edited my .gitconfig:

```
[merge "mytool"]
name = union merge
driver = ./union-merge.sh %A %O %B
```

I can check that the .gitattributes file indeed sets the merge attribute for all files:

```
$ git check-attr -a src/file.cpp
customn/appopt.cpp: merge: mytool
```

However, my script is not being executed (I added the echo just to make sure). Instead, a normal git merge is performed, leaving me with the contents of the other branch. How can I do this properly?

Edit.: some more information:

This is the history

```
    A --- B ------- D    (master)
           \       /
            ---C---      (toolbranch)
```

At **B**, I have commited my changes. I created a new branch from there, used the above mentioned code generator to generate the method skeletons (and some marker comments it uses which are needed). This step has removed my changes at **B**, because the previous model was based on **A**, and I commited this code on toolbranch. Now I want to merge back to **master** and keep both the contents from **B** and **C** in order to be able to manually insert my implementations to the method skeletons. The problem here is that git does not see this as a conflict, since it thinks that in commit **C** the lines were legitimately removed and the new method skeletons were inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I'm not sure if I got your problem right, but basically a `mergetool` is not executed automatically on merge.

The standard workflow is that you make a `git merge`, then when there is a conflict git tells you that about it so you decide how to resolve issue. Then if you say `git mergetool` it will ask you which tool to use to resolve it. After setting your `union-merge` as above, it should require only a simple `ENTER` to call your script and do the custom processing of these files.

Comment: I have added some more explanation. The problem is that my script is not being called and git thinks there are no conflicts.